# Unity: Defining a new class new class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below the given class, I want to make a new class below the provided one but it gives an error.

```
public class apicall : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }
}


public class  responseData
{
  public string status { get; set; }
  public dataClass data { get; set; }

}
```

ERROR:

```
Assets/apicall.cs(39,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'dataClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: I can't see dataClass anywhere in this code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this property:

```
public dataClass data { get; set; }
```

The compiler does not know of any class that goes by that partial name.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class  responseData
{
  public string status { get; set; }
  public dataClass data { get; set; }

}
```

You never actually declared a class 'dataClass' but you are trying to create a 'dataClass' variable. You need to declare a 'dataClass' somewhere

```
public class dataClass {
//variables
//methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know about your class `dataClass`, did you declare it in a different namespace?

```
using namespace;
```

At the top of your file. This should fix your problem.